# "missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value..." when POSTing accessToken request on linkedin API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, post, linkedin-api, access-token

I am following [authentication doc](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) for fetching the user profile details after authentication on linkedin.

I have successfully completed the first step to `GET` the `authorization_code`. But when i do a `POST` in the second step using same `authorization_code` and `redirect_uri` as the previous request, i get following response:

> {"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : client_id","error":"invalid_request"}

I have checked the parameters to `POST` request multiple number of times and don't find anything wrong there e.g. using the correct `authorization_code` and `redirect_uri`.

Also read some of the answers to similar issue, most of them say that `authorization_code` expires in less than 10 or 20 seconds. But in my case, `POST` request uses the `authorization_code` within 1 second of receiving it in Step 1. So, expiration should not be a problem here.

I am using `Rails` 3.0.7 and `Net::HTTP` to send the `POST` request. I have tried adding parameters to the URL as well as to request's body. Neither of them worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you put the parameters in the URL? I found that the API does not accept parameters posted as form parameters.

Comment: thanks @KeesdeKooter . this solved the issue for me

Comment: @KeesdeKooter, do i need to pass parameters in Body or in URL(header) itself? i tried both ways. It's not working